# how to enable routerLink in mat-tab

Tags: angular

I am lazy loading a feature module as shown in Routing.module.ts from an app-routing.module.ts. The default route in featured routing module load the LccpTrackerComponent which contains 3 child routes.  The template for the LccpTrackerComponent uses Angular Material tab component.  I am trying to add the routerLink directive in the mat-tab title to route to a corresponding child component, but the route doesn't fire.  Does anyone know how to make this work?  Thanks.

**Template**

```html
<article>
  <section>
    <mat-tab-group>
      <mat-tab label="Consults"><a routerLink="consults" /></mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Screening"><a routerLink="screening" /></mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Noduled"><a routerLink="noduled" /></mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
  </section>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</article>
```

**Routing.module.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: LccpTrackerComponent,
  children: [{
      path: 'consults',
      component: ConsultComponent,
      pathMatch: 'full',
      resolve: {
        consultSummary: LccpResolver
      }
    },
    {
      path: 'screening',
      component: ScreeningComponent,
      pathMatch: 'full',
      resolve: {
        enrolledSummary: ScreeningResolver
      }
    },
    {
      path: 'noduled',
      component: NoduledComponent,
      pathMatch: 'full',
      resolve: {
        noduledSummary: NoduledResolver
      }
    }
  ]
}, ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LccpRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>`, from the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#tabs-and-navigation):

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
 <a mat-tab-link
   *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
   [routerLink]="link.path"
   routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
   [active]="rla.isActive">
  {{link.label}}
 </a>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, use `<a [routerLink]="['/LinkPath']">` is fine.

But I also recommend you that can use page tag as routing since you've
define the selector,

like path: 'consults' -> use `<consults></consults>`

For example :

```
<mat-tab-group>
   <mat-tab label="Consults"><consults</consults>></mat-tab>
   <mat-tab label="Screening"><screening></screening></mat-tab>
   <mat-tab label="Noduled"><noduled></noduled></mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Besides, if you are worried about the loading, 
you can use `[selectIndex]` method (Might different from your material version)
to fulfill the same purpose.